# Projection of finite dimensional space with ell infinity norm

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces, banach-spaces, projection, contraction-mapping

Consider $\mathbb{R}^n$ with $\ell_{\infty}$ norm. Let $Y \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a linear subspace with dimension $r < n$.

I am considering the following projection: for each $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$,
$P(x) := \text{argmin}_{y \in Y} ||y - x ||_{\infty}$.

I know that it may not be well defined because there might be multiple $y$'s to achieve the minimum. If this is the case, I can choose one of them which has the minimum $\ell_2$ norm, i.e.
$P(x) := \{y \in \text{argmin}_{y \in Y} ||y - x ||_{\infty} : \forall y' \in \text{argmin}_{y \in Y} ||y - x ||_{\infty}, ||y||_2 \leq ||y'||\}.$

Then, I think it is well-defined since $\ell_2$ norm is strictly convex. Also, I believe that this projection is continuous with respect to $\ell_{\infty}$ norm.

Let's define
\begin{equation*}
 ||P||_{\infty} := \sup_{||X||_{\infty} \leq 1} ||P(X)||_{\infty}.
\end{equation*}

My question is, is $P$ non-expansive? In other words, is it true that $||P||_{\infty} \leq 1$?

I googled this and only found that [Bound on projection to finite dimensional subspace of Banach Space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2244792/bound-on-projection-to-finite-dimensional-subspace-of-banach-space) .

But, what I really want is the non-expansiveness. Is it false in general?

Thanks.

Comment: do you think P is linear? Otherwise, how do you define $\|P\|_{\infty}$?

Comment: You're right. Even such $P$ is not linear. But, can we still define a norm properly?

Comment: norms are defined on vector spaces. which vector space do you assume that $P$ belongs to? I think you should explicitly define what you mean by $\|P\|$.

Comment: by the way, $P$ satisfies $P(\alpha x) = \alpha P(x)$ for any scalar $\alpha$ and $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: $Y$ is a subspace. I edited that point.

Comment: a direct question: would you define $\|P\|_{\infty}$ to be $=\sup\{\|P(x)\|_{\infty}: \|x\|_{\infty}=1\}$? If not, how do you define it? Please write it down explicitly in your post. In case $\|P\|_{\infty}=\sup\{\|P(x)\|_{\infty}: \|x\|_{\infty}=1\}$, I think the answer to your question is "no".

Comment: Can you give me a counter example?

Comment: Take $Y=\{(2t,t):t\in\mathbb{R}\}$, $x=(1,1)$. Let $s$ satisfy $-(1+2s) = 1+s$ and $y=(2s,s)$. Then, $P(x) = y$ and $\|P(x)\|_\infty>1=\|x\|_{\infty}$.

Comment: correction: let $y=(-2s,-s) = (4/3,2/3)$.